# C# WP8 AddRefference TargetPlatform Switch failed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WP 8.1 project - WP_Proj_8.1
Then try to add a WP 8.0 project as Lib - WP_Proj_8.0 (OpticalReaderLib)

```
I right Click on the 8.1 Porject,
AddRefference,
select the WP_Proj_8.0,
Hit OK
```

Then failed, something like this popped out:

```
Unable to add a reference to project <WP_Proj_8.0>
```

Then I upgrade the 8.0 project to 8.1. 
But it was upgraded to the 8.1 Silverlight. I don't know it matters or not.
But when add reference, still failed.

Then I try to check the target framework of both projects,

But both of the project has no  select box!

[image]
So what I can do to add the  to a WP8.1 project?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your 8.1 project is 8.1 XAML (WinRT). You cannot mix WinRT with Silverlight. You have to rewrite your 8.0 library to WinRT or find a WinRT one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
But how do I know my 8.1 is XAML or not?

Comment: Thank you very much again, I already know what is WinRT,
So I can't use the lib, 
is that because,
A WinRT 8.1 can't use WinRT 8.0 ?

Comment: Look at your project in the Solution Explorer. if it say Windows Phone 8.1 nect to the name, then it is XAML (WinRT). If it says Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight is Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

```
OK, I completely know what's going on there.
For those who want to upgrade WP8.0 to WP8.1,
It's impossible.

XAML(WinRT) and Silverlight are 2 completely different stuff.
And there's no way to add a Silverlight ref from a XAML(WinRT)

[WP8.0] is a short name for [WP8.0 SilverLight]
So after upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1, 
It became [WP8.1 SilverLight], that's what is should be.

So for those who wanna upgrade a [WP8.0] to [WP8.1],
It's impossible,
because you're trying to upgrade [WP8.0 Silverlight] to [WP8.1 RT]
You need to re-create a project and manually upgrade them.
That's pretty much of it.
Thanks for the answer, lgor Kulman.

WP sucks! Damn!
```

Comment: You can upgrade from WP8.0 to WP8.1 *Silverlight*. *WinRT* and *Silverlight* are different API's.

Comment: Here what I'm saying is it's impossible to upgrade from WP8.0 to WP8.1 RT, because WP8.0 is a short for WP8.0 silverlight.

Comment: With this you are right. WinRT is new API, working different, designed to target multiple devices, not only phones, therefore needs to be handeled different way. As you have mentioned, conversion from WP8.0 to WP8.1RT has to be done manually.